# TabTemplate example in android automotive OS

Tags: android-auto, android-automotive, automotive

Any one have any idea to make Tab layout functionality in android automotive OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app-samples/showcase/common/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/sample/showcase/common/screens/templatelayouts/tabtemplates/TabTemplateDemoScreen.java shows a sample screen built using the `TabTemplate`.

Comment: but when I try to `import androidx.car.app.model.TabTemplate;` it gives error

Comment: What version of the `androidx.car.app:app` artifact are you using? You might need to update to a newer version

Comment: Updaing to latest solves the issue, Thanks! I have few more questions on android auto if you can have a look in SO..

Comment: but again I see that it's not possible to test in emulator yet because there's no system image available for android api 34. also are there examples of tab templates  in use ?

Comment: There isn't currently an API 34 emulator image for Android Automotive OS (and there are also no cars on the road running API 34). Could you use one of the lower API level emulators https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#generic-images?

Comment: yes it runs if i use `androidx.car.app:app` version 1.3.0-rc01 but if I try to use 1.4.0-rc01 it gives error : `Dependency 'androidx.car.app:app:1.4.0-rc01' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.`

Comment: Ah, for that you need to bump the `compileSdk` in your `build.gradle` file - the API level of the emulator doesn't matter.